# Parsing a time string using regex and converting to integer

Tags: regex, vba, visual-studio, time

I want to allow users to input a time in a masked text box and then validate that time and convert it if necessary for later saving.

I've tried a method of validating the time using only regex but honestly could not find very detailed answers. I decided to simply separate the string the user inputs into its base components and then convert the chunks of time into integers for easy comparison.

'''

```
Public Function CreateTimeString(TheTime As String, TheSuffix As String) As String 'wip
    Dim Hour As String = "00"
    Dim Minute As String = "00"
    Dim inthour As Integer
    Dim intminute As Integer
    Dim pattern As String = "(?<hour>\d*?):(?<minute>\d*?)"
    For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(TheTime, pattern)
        Hour = m.Groups("hour").Value
        Minute = m.Groups("minute").Value
    Next

    inthour = Convert.ToInt32(Hour)
    intminute = Convert.ToInt32(Minute)

    TxtMeals.Text = Hour & ":" & Minute
End Function
```

'''

An error occurs when attempting to convert Minute string into an integer. Commenting this out and testing shows the Hour has been successfully converted. It appears that Minute cannot be found.
Example strings:
12:12
 1:23
 4:55
10:45
Also, if I change pattern by adding a space just before the last quotation mark neither are found and I would like to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `m.Groups("minute").Value` will not be found because you are using a non greedy match for `\d*?` for the minutes part there is no end boundary set like for example `$` so it will match at least as possible which will be 0 times.

You could use:

```
(?<hour>\d+):(?<minute>\d+)
```

You might use a more precise match, for example for 12 hour time use:

```
(?<hour>1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):(?<minute>[0-5][0-9])
```

Or 24h time:

```
(?<hour>[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):(?<minute>[0-5][0-9])
```

You might opt to use anchors `^` and `$` to assert the start and the end of the string.

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3chour%3e%5b01%5d%3f%5b0-9%5d%7c2%5b0-3%5d%29%3a%28%3f%3cminute%3e%5b0-5%5d%5b0-9%5d%29&i=12%3a12%0d%0a1%3a23%0d%0a4%3a55%0d%0a10%3a45) | [vb.net demo](https://ideone.com/k0Wlub)

Comment: Much obliged, the first code example you gave works quite well. As for the precise matching, I need to convert the hours and minutes anyway to that I can convert it from a 12 hour format to a 24 hour format, so I might as well just test if its converted values are valid.